# Using python dataframe for map-reduce

Tags: pandas, hadoop

Is there a way I can use pandas dataframe as a streaming source in Hadoop map-reduce?

Here is exactly what I am doing now and what I would want .

Currently I am using pandas dataframe to load data from a csv.
And then I am using some intermediate dataframes for calculation and storing result.

But as the script continues to run the processing speed slows up.

Is there a way pandas dataframe can be use along with the map-reduce on hadoop?

The question is vague but is there a way?

Comment: you have to install pandas in all your Data Nodes ( slaves).

Comment: You may want to have a look at Apache Spark;